# TCPDF generated PDF to automatically display in Acrobat Reader

Tags: tcpdf

I am able to use TCPDF and generate a PDF in the browser using JQuery/JavaScript:

```
window.open("", "pdfWindow",scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
$("#" + formID).attr('action','tcpdf/example/genReport.pdf').attr('target','pdfWindow');
```

In genReport.pdf, I am using `$pdf->Output('genReport.pdf', 'I');`

When genReport.pdf is generated, it appears in a new tab with the standard browser settings. I wanted to know if there is a way to have the generated PDF automatically display in Acrobat Reader?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation of the output() function, the second parameter can be one of those:

> - I: send the file inline to the browser (default). The plug-in is used    if available. The name given by name is used when one selects
>     the    "Save as" option on the link generating the PDF.
> - D: send to the    browser and force a file download with the name given by name.
> - F:  save to a local server file with the name given by name.
> - S: return the document as a string (name is ignored).
> - FI: equivalent to F + I    option
> - FD: equivalent to F + D option
> - E: return the document as base64 mime multi-part email attachment (RFC 2045)

So I'd suggest using  `$pdf->Output('genReport.pdf', 'D');` this will open the download dialog and the user can choose to either open or download the file.

Comment: @ Salketer, this is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thanks a bunch. After open is selected, there is some lag time before the report is rendered. Is there a way to have a load icon while the PDF is being generated?